# Batch query to webservice returns "The Uri string is too long"

Tags: c#, web-services, http-post, wcf-data-services, http-get

I'm trying to send big request to server and get big data. So i use batch request to Data Service. URI of this request looks like this "hxxp://company/Test.svc/$batch". I'm using .Net 4.0

I send valid POST request:

```
DataServiceRequest[] Request = new DataServiceRequest[]{new DataServiceRequest<TTable>((query).RequestUri)};
try
{
    DataServiceResponse dsr = WebService.ExecuteBatch(Request);
    foreach (QueryOperationResponse qr in dsr)
    {
        if (qr.Query.ElementType == typeof(TTable))
        {
            foreach (TTable item in qr) { list.Add(item); }
        }
    }
}
```

And recieve an error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="ru-RU">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
  <innererror>
    <message>Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.</message>
    <type>System.UriFormatException</type>
    <stacktrace>   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)&#xD;
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.GetAbsoluteUriFromReference(String reference, Uri absoluteServiceUri)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.BatchServiceHost..ctor(Uri absoluteServiceUri, BatchStream batchStream, String contentId, String boundary, StreamWriter writer)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.BatchDataService.CreateOperationContextFromBatchStream(Uri absoluteServiceUri, BatchStream batchStream, HashSet`1 contentIds, String boundary, StreamWriter writer)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.BatchDataService.HandleBatchContent(Stream responseStream)</stacktrace>
  </innererror>
</error>
```

It seems like server side exception, occures when it try to parse big uri. How to avoid this limitation?

**MODIFIED (28/01/2013 at 16:00)**

IIS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" maxQueryString="209715000" maxUrl="2000000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
    <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800"
      maxQueryStringLength="2097150" 
      maxUrlLength="2097150"
      relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
       maxRequestLength="500000000"
      requestValidationMode="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, I believe you can increase the max URL size by going to Request Filtering > Edit Feature Settings > Maximum URL Length.

The following guide should help you out further: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits